# need to load the field dynamically based on selectbox value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to load the form fields dynamically based on the select box.consider my selectbox contain four values.If I choose 3 my form with display thrice with dynamic field name.

```html
<form method="POST">
  <table border=1> 
    <tr>
      <td>
       <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label col-md-4">First  Name:</label>
 <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input type="text" name="V1_Fname" >
           
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
     </td>
     <td>
       <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label col-md-4">Last   Name:</label>
 <div class="col-md-8">
                     <input type="text" name="V1_Lname" ">
                 </div>
           </div>
       </div>  
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
       <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label col-md-4">Relation to Member:</label>
 <div class="col-md-8">
                    <select size="1" name="V1_Relation">
                <option selected="selected"></option>
            <option value="SP">Spouse</option>
            <option value="Son">Son</option>
             <option value="Daughter">Daughter</option>
            <option  value="F">Father</option>
           <option   value="M">Mother</option>
             <option value="MIL">Mother-in-   value="OTH">Other</option>
            </select>
           
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
     </td>
     <td>
      
      </td>
   </tr>

</table>
</form>
```

I need this form load thrice If I choose 3 in select box.
  I tried with jquery

```js
   
$(document).ready(function() {
$('select#insured').change(function() {
var sel_value = $('select#insured').val();
if (sel_value == 0) {
$("#form_submit").empty(); // Resetting Form
$("#form1").css({
'display': 'none'
});
} else {

$("#form_submit").empty(); //Resetting Form
// Below Function Creates Input Fields Dynamically
create(sel_value);
// Appending Submit Button To Form
$("#form_submit").append($("<input/>", {
type: 'submit',
value: 'Register'
}))
}
});
function create(sel_value) {
// alert(sel_value);
for (var i = 1; i <= sel_value; i++) {
$("div#form1").slideDown('slow');
$("div#form1").append($("#form_submit").append($("<div/>", {
id: 'head'
}).append($("<h3/>").text("Visitor" + i)), $("<input/>", {
type: 'text',
placeholder: 'Name' + i,
name: 'firstName_' + i
}), $("<br/>"), $("<input/>", {
type: 'text',
placeholder: 'Last Name' + i,
name: 'lastName_' + i
}), $("<br/>"), $("<input/>", {
placeholder: 'Age' + i,
type: 'text',
name: 'Age_' + i
}), $("<br/>"), $("<hr/>"), $("<br/>")))
}
}
});
</script>
```

```html
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <select class="form-control" name="insured" id="insured">
         <option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
         <option value="3">3</option>
         <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>

<div id="form1">
     <div id="form_submit">
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: And have you tried coding something besides dumping an html here? If the answer is yes, dump that code here aswell..

Comment: please check my updated post